# Three.js - centroid of boxHelper

Tags: three.js

I have used the following to calculate the centroid of an imported model;

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var centroid = new THREE.Vector3();
centroid.addVectors( geometry.boundingBox.min, geometry.boundingBox.max );
centroid.multiplyScalar( - 0.5 );
centroid.applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25269787

It works well, but I think BoundingBox has been deprecated.
Should I be using boxHelper? How do I find centroid of boxHelper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [`BoundingBoxHelper` was deprecated](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/10197), not the `boundingBox` property.

2) Don't use `BoxHelper` to find the centroid. Just use the `boundingBox` property.

2.5) The `boundingBox` property is a `Box3` object, which has a `getCenter` method, which gives you what you're calculating.

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var centroid = geometry.boundingBox.getCenter();
centroid.applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );
```