# Finding the centroid of a closed path (polygon) in PaperJS

Tags: javascript, geometry, paperjs

I have switched over from Python's Shapely to JavaScript's PaperJS. I would like to find the centroid of polygon or closed Path as it is called PaperJS. Is there a quick way to do it or will I have to write my own algorithm?

Comment: Did you read the paper.js documentation? What did that say about the API for paths/polygons?

Comment: A quick google brings up the algorithm https://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KtzLq/, but proceed with caution, as it's not clear (at least to me) that it actually produces the centroid.  Also, if you are shifting to a new library, you might want to consider the jump to threejs, which appears to have a built-in centroid function.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267003 .

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on the bounding box created by the poligon path?

Each item created in Paperjs has a **bounds** property that returns a **Rectangle** object, this Rectangle object will have a **center** property that returns the center of the object

[Item.bounds](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#bounds)

Hope that helps

Comment: The centroid is the geometric center of a shape. Paper.js returns the center of the bounds when called path.bounds.center.